# How to synchronize contentReferences from Salesforce to Heroku using Heroku connect

Tags: contentdocument, heroku, heroku-connect

I am trying to synchronize the data from our SalesForce org to Heroku platform using Heroku Connect. I have few custom objects with Rich Text area field, within which there are contentReferences (eg: https://xxx.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a7B1A00000000R&feoid=00NC0000005daDu&refid=0EM1A000000DEh

what is the best approach to synch these data in Heroku?

As I am new to Heroku any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/quickstart-heroku-connect ?